# How do I empty a list pgfmath randomlist

Tags: tikz-pgf, random-numbers

I'm trying to use `\pgfmathrandomlist`s.

I know that the command `\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{list}{{item1}{item2}...}` produces a list and that the command `\pgfmathrandomitem` select a random item from a list.

Once I have created and used the list for what I need, I would like to empty the list so that I can use a new list with the same name. I tryed `\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{list}{}` but it does not work.

Comment: I tried also \pgfdeclaremathrandomlist{list}{{}} but it does not work either

Comment: Can you be more specific on how it "does not work"? A minimal (non-)working example would help here. If you use `\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{list}{{item3}{item4}...}` after some initial usage of the command, the contents in `{list}`, i.e. `{item1}{item2}...`, will simply get replaced by `{item3}{item4}...`

Comment: Macros can be thought of as string pointers.  You don't need to "empty" a list, just create a new one and point to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no internal mechanism by which `\pgfmathrandomitem` truly knows whether a list is empty. The case below shows this anomaly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pgfmathclearrandomlist}[1]{%
  \expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{list}{{item1}{item2}{item3}{item4}}
\pgfmathrandomitem{\result}{list}\result% Returns item1/item2/item3/item4

\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{list}{}
\pgfmathrandomitem{\result}{list}\result% Returns item1

\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{list}{{}}
\pgfmathrandomitem{\result}{list}\result% Returns {}

\pgfmathclearrandomlist{list}
\pgfmathrandomitem{\result}{list}\result% List doesn't exist

\end{document}
```

The first instruction set creates a list with four items, from which a random one is selected. The second instruction "clears" this list, although the output is always the first item in the previously-defined list - `item1`. You can visually clear the list by giving it a single item that is empty - `{}`, but that may not help. Perhaps the solution would be to update the way `\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist` works when being assigned an empty list (this would be a marginal update/patch, since it seems like a bug), or clear it officially using `\pgfmathclearrandomlist`.